# How to get Jest working with an in-memory MongoDB server?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jestjs

I am making my first tentative steps into modern JS development, and to do so, I am writing an app, with the intention of running it on Mongo Stitch. I am trying to stick to TDD-ish development, partly because it is good practice, and partly because it is much easier to run things locally than in the Stitch environment.

I have a working Docker/Alpine environment, and it runs unit tests against Stitch functions fine using Jest. However, I am now writing functions where the conditionals/logic are in Mongo, so unit tests are not enough to protect against regressions.

My original plan was to spin up a MongoDB 4.0 instance in Docker Compose, and then work out how to connect to it in Jest. However, [the Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb) have pointed me to an in-memory MongoDB, which sounds pretty good. Unfortunately it seems non-trivial to set up, and I am bumping into a number of errors.

I am using Yarn to pull dependencies. Since this appears to compile some binaries, I wondered if my being on Alpine was complicating things (BusyBox builds tend to be a bit trickier). I have therefore swapped to Ubuntu. My Dockerfile is pretty simple:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl gnupg
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install runtime and test tools
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn --no-install-recommends yarn
RUN yarn global add jest @shelf/jest-mongodb mongodb-memory-server

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

The docs indicate I need something called a preset, which is kept in `package.json`:

```
{
    "jest": {
        "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb"
    }
}
```

This is what the Yarn installation command looks like (and I wonder if the "no binaries" warnings is relevant):

```
yarn global v1.21.1
warning package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "mongodb@3.x.x".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "jest@24.9.0" with binaries:
      - jest
warning "@shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3" has no binaries
warning "mongodb-memory-server@6.1.1" has no binaries
Done in 68.90s.
```

Finally here is a Jest run, which fails immediately:

```
# jest
● Validation Error:

  Preset @shelf/jest-mongodb not found.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

I have also tried `yarn global add jest @shelf/jest-mongodb mongodb-memory-server --dev` (i.e. adding the `--dev` flag) and this makes no difference.

It looks like the problem is with the preset, but as far as I can tell, my preset matches what the docs suggest. What should I try next?

Comment: (Aside: I may switch back to using a separate container for Mongo for now, on the basis that this will not need the preset thing, and thus I can get going again. However, getting the in-memory version would still be interesting to me, and I'd happily part with a bounty if I can tempt someone into leading me in a useful direction).

Comment: This might be an issue related to how you are installing the packages. Remove the `global` option in the install command so that it becomes something like this: `yarn add jest @shelf/jest-mongodb mongodb-memor`. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: @OTZ: marvellous, thanks - I think that might be it. I did the following: (1) removed the `global` option in the `Dockerfile` and rebuilt it; (2) ran the tests using `node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`, and this loaded a Node binary before running the tests. Would you like to add an answer - and perhaps speculate why this fixes it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why that fixes the issue, however, my best explanation would be that installing the packages globally downloads them somewhere the process running in the docker container, can't access, hence, it spits out the `Preset @shelf/jest-mongodb not found.` error.

Comment: Thanks again @OTZ. I have written it up as best I can.

Comment: _(Note to readers: this post has attracted some serial downvotes, I suspect one of which will be removed by the reversal script. I suspect my editing has made someone grumpy)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved by @OTZ in the comments; I am expanding on the solution here for reference.

The original Yarn install command in the `Dockerfile` was thus:

```
yarn global add jest @shelf/jest-mongodb mongodb-memory-server
```

The solution was to remove the `global` keyword so that it became:

```
yarn        add jest @shelf/jest-mongodb mongodb-memory-server
```

It was speculated that the first version did not work because the dependencies were placed somewhere in the Docker image where they could not be found.

The different outputs during the build are interesting. Here is a (trimmed) successful stdout snippet:

```
yarn add v1.21.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "mongodb@3.x.x".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 352 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3
├─ jest@24.9.0
└─ mongodb-memory-server@6.1.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/generator@7.7.7
├─ @babel/helper-function-name@7.7.4
├─ @babel/helper-get-function-arity@7.7.4
├─ @babel/helper-split-export-declaration@7.7.4
├─ @babel/helpers@7.7.4
├─ @babel/highlight@7.5.0
├─ @babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@7.7.4
├─ @cnakazawa/watch@1.0.3
├─ @jest/core@24.9.0
├─ @jest/reporters@24.9.0
├─ @jest/source-map@24.9.0
├─ @jest/test-sequencer@24.9.0
├─ @shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3
├─ @types/babel__core@7.1.3
├─ @types/babel__generator@7.6.1
├─ @types/babel__template@7.0.2
├─ @types/babel__traverse@7.0.8
...
```

This appears to list all dependencies I have asked for. However if I use `global` I get this:

```
yarn global v1.21.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest > jest-cli > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "mongodb@3.x.x".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "jest@24.9.0" with binaries:
      - jest
warning "@shelf/jest-mongodb@1.1.3" has no binaries
warning "mongodb-memory-server@6.1.1" has no binaries
```

It appears to have installed Jest, but not two other items, and the dependency tree is not rendered.

Additional answers that explain why this happens are welcome, but this appears to be my fix for now.